# Multiple columns within a single CASE statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm sure this has be covered many times so please pardon my repeat. I have a query that works but currently has 6 CASE statements within one select. Someone mentioned that it would be best optimized by putting all my WHEN conditions within a single CASE. However, I'm unable to achieve this

```
select right(RTRIM(region),5) as cell_id, 
     sum(CASE WHEN LEFT(cparty,3) in ('999','998','997') THEN chargeduration/60 else 0 END) AS OnNet_Minutes,
     sum(CASE WHEN LEFT(cparty,3) in ('996','995') THEN chargeduration/60 else 0 END) AS OffNet_C_Minutes,
     sum(CASE WHEN LEFT(cparty,3) in ('994','993','992') THEN chargeduration/60 else 0 END) AS OffNet_A_Minutes,
     sum(CASE WHEN LEFT(cparty,3) in ('991','990') THEN chargeduration/60 else 0 END) AS OffNet_S_Minutes,
     sum(CASE WHEN LEFT(cparty,2) = '00' THEN chargeduration/60 else 0 END) AS OffNet_T_Minutes,
     sum(CASE WHEN len(cparty) < 6 and LEFT(cparty,1) <> 0 THEN chargeduration/60 else 0 END) AS SC_Minutes            
  from August.dbo.cdr20130818 
  where CHARGEDURATION > 0 and ISNULL(region,'''')<>'''' and LEN(region) > 5
group by right(RTRIM(region),5)
order by right(RTRIM(region),5) asc
```

Comment: Do you want a single, summed column for charge duration in your output, or six?

Comment: You should ask the person what they meant.  Your query looks fine as it is.

Comment: A single `CASE` *expression* would mean that you would get a single column, is that ok with you?

Comment: The logic is to have 6 columns returning 6 different breakdown for the data.

Comment: If you need 6 columns returning 6 different values, then you are doing it fine

Answer (score 4):

In your case, you can't put them all into one `CASE`, since the results all go into different columns of the select.

BTW, you should remove your `ISNULL(region, '''') <> ''''` condition, as it's redundant when paired with the `LEN(region) > 5` condition. (When `region` is null, then `LEN(region)` is also null, and `NULL > 5` is false.)

Comment: Changing the condition to what you said is not the same thing. What about region that are really equal to '' and not null...?

Comment: @FabienTheSolution In general, I'd agree with you, but notice the `LEN(region) > 5` condition afterwards? That'd filter out the case you mentioned.

Comment: So may be `and LEN(ISNULL(region,'''')) > 5` instead of `and ISNULL(region,'''')<>'''' and LEN(region) > 5` :)

Comment: Really, at that point, you may as well just use `LEN(region) > 5` and rely on the fact that when `region` is null, `LEN(region)` is also null and `NULL > 5` is false. (I do agree with your point in general.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have it right, six different `SUM()`'s that each have meaning on their own.

If all of your criteria were in the same `CASE` statement you'd lose detail, you'd be returning the `SUM()` of your currently separate statements combined into one.

Combining redundant criteria in the `WHERE` clause can clean up a `CASE` statement, but you don't have anything completely redundant here.