# do i need to rewrite the case statement for every field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The case condition for two columns is same.in the below statement am using this twice but for different column, is there any other way for not repeating the condition twice ??

```
case [CPHIL_AWD_CD]
                     when ' ' then 'Not Applicable/ Not a Doctoral Student'
                     when 'X' then 'Not Applicable/ Not a Doctoral Student'
                     when 'N' then 'NO'
                     when 'Y' then 'YES'
                end as CPHIL_AWD_CD

              ,case [FINL_ORAL_REQ_CD] 
                     when ' ' then 'Not Applicable/ Not a Doctoral Student'
                     when 'X' then 'Not Applicable/ Not a Doctoral Student'
                     when 'N' then 'NO'
                     when 'Y' then 'YES'
                end as FINL_ORAL_REQ_CD
```

Comment: Option A) Create a reference table that has the values in it and join to that table twice  B) Create function in SQL that you can call

Comment: This is a comlelling question, but [the answer appears to be no](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341192/multiple-columns-within-a-single-case-statement).

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I agree with you.

Comment: If this is needed only in this query instead of a reference table a CTE is good enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variation on thepirat000's answer:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Samples as Table (
  Frisbee Int Identity Primary Key, Code1 Char(1), Code2 Char(2) );
insert into @Samples values ( 'Y', 'N' ), ( ' ', 'Y' ), ( 'N', 'X' );
select * from @Samples;

-- Handle the lookup.
with Lookup as (
  select * from ( values
    ( ' ', 'Not Applicable/ Not a Doctoral Student' ),
    ( 'X', 'Not Applicable/ Not a Doctoral Student' ),
    ( 'N', 'No' ),
    ( 'Y', 'Yes' ) ) as TableName( Code, Description ) )
select S.Code1, L1.Description, S.Code2, L2.Description
    from @Samples as S inner join
      Lookup as L1 on L1.Code = S.Code1 inner join
      Lookup as L2 on L2.Code = S.Code2;
```

The lookup table is created within a CTE and referenced as needed for multiple columns.

**Update:** The table variable is now blessed with a primary key for some inexplicable reason. If someone can actually explain how it will benefit performance, I'd love to hear it. It isn't obvious from the execution plan.

Comment: If you are going to use a table variable then I suggest you still declare a primary key

Comment: @Frisbee - Please enlighten me on the benefit to adding an PK to `@Samples`, the _table variable_, in this example. There might be some benefit to making the `Code` column in the lookup table a PK, but that is a [table value constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) and there is no syntax, AFAIK, for specifying keys. In thepirat000's solution the lookup table is a table variable and might benefit from a PK, although I would suspect that a lookup table this small will not show a performance benefit. What am I missing?

Comment: If it is a unique (PK) then once the join finds one it knows it can it can stop.  And there is the whole index thing.

Comment: @Frisbee - Would `Code1` or `Code2` make a more useful primary key? They're both used in joins. Or index both and add an identity column as a PK?

Comment: see answer from thepirat00

Answer (score 4):

Just create a table (temp?) with the mapping

```
CREATE TABLE [Constants]
(
    [ID] nvarchar(1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Text] nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO [Constants] VALUES (' ', 'Not Applicable/ Not a Doctoral Student')
INSERT INTO [Constants] VALUES ('X', 'Not Applicable/ Not a Doctoral Student')
INSERT INTO [Constants] VALUES ('N', 'No')
INSERT INTO [Constants] VALUES ('Y', 'Yes')
```

and perform an inner join

```
SELECT C1.Text AS CPHIL_AWD_CD, C2.Text AS FINL_ORAL_REQ_CD, ...
FROM YourTable T
INNER JOIN Constants C1 ON C1.ID = T.CPHIL_AWD_CD
INNER JOIN Constants C2 ON C2.ID = T.FINL_ORAL_REQ_CD
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the suggestion from Dijkgraaf, here is the solution:

Create a function with the logic in it and call that in the select statement:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetCaseValue (@val varchar(50))
RETURNS varchar(50)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
return (select case @val
                     when ' ' then 'Not Applicable/ Not a Doctoral Student'
                     when 'X' then 'Not Applicable/ Not a Doctoral Student'
                     when 'N' then 'NO'
                     when 'Y' then 'YES'
                end)
END
```

And call it like:

```
select dbo.GetCaseValue([CPHIL_AWD_CD]) as 'CPHIL_AWD_CD',
    dbo.GetCaseValue([FINL_ORAL_REQ_CD]) as 'FINL_ORAL_REQ_CD'
```

Comment: If you use the CASE WHEN, you can avoid the duplicated string also: `CASE WHEN [CPHIL_AWD_CD] IN (' ', 'X') THEN 'Not Applicable/ Not a Doctoral Student' WHEN [CPHIL_AWD_CD] = 'N' THEN 'NO' ... END as CPHIL_AWD_CD`

Comment: This would certainly work but there can be overheads to calling functions that might reveal themselves in large data sets

Comment: adding to LozInSpace's comment - scalar udfs can suffer performance issues. An inline table valued udf may perform better (although may not be as nice to use in cases like this).

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  What you are doing is, to the best of my knowledge, correct.

You COULD make a user defined function as below, but the benefits are .. subjective.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnMungeIt (
    @In NVARCHAR(1)
)

RETURNS NVARCHAR(255)

BEGIN

RETURN          CASE @In
                     when ' ' then 'Not Applicable/ Not a Doctoral Student'
                     when 'X' then 'Not Applicable/ Not a Doctoral Student'
                     when 'N' then 'NO'
                     when 'Y' then 'YES'
                END

END

--

SELECT          dbo.ufnMungeIt([CPHIL_AWD_CD]) AS CPHIL_AWD_CD,
                dbo.ufnMungeIt([FINL_ORAL_REQ_CD]) AS FINL_ORAL_REQ_CD
```