# Getting a value indicating whether entries fulfil a specific condition in SQL

Tags: sql, entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-6

There is a table `OrderingDate` with a `timestamp` as column.

`OrderingDate (Id, Timestamp, [other columns...])`

I want to get a boolean indicating whether there is any ordering date inside of a specific time range or not, e.g. from `01-01-2015 00:00` to `01-01-2015 23:59`. The concrete entries are not relevant at all, only the value is needed. Unfortunately I need the information for an enumeration of time ranges, e.g. are there any ordering dates for `01-01-2015`, `06-04-2015`, `09-09-2015` (each as time range) and so on.

The time ranges must not be correlate with a normal day, e.g. from `01-01-2015 02:00` to `02-01-2015 01:59` must be supported as well. The time ranges must not be contiguous (gaps between the time ranges are possible).

**What would be the sql query with the best performance to solve the problem?**

My current solution (one query for each time range) is very slow for the large table (100,000 entries+) :|.

I use the Entity Framework (v6) for accessing the database. If the framework provide any good approach to solve the problem, please share it. For testing I would use T-SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what "time ranges must not be coherent" means.

A null means it does not exists

```
declare @dates table (dateStart datetime, dateEnd datetime);
insert into @dates values (2000-01-01, 2000-01-02) 
                        , (2000-01-01, 2000-01-02)
                        , (cast('2011-10-28 12:26:00' as datetime), cast('2011-10-28 12:26:00' as datetime));
select docSVsys.sID, docSVsys.addDate, [@dates].dateStart
 from docSVsys 
 left join @dates 
  on docSVsys.addDate >= [@dates].dateStart 
 and docSVsys.addDate <= [@dates].dateEnd;
```

Comment: "If you are going to use a table variable then I suggest you still declare a primary key – Frisbee" unless it's just sample data to illustrate a point.

Comment: @HABO Illustrate a point?  What you had on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883092/do-i-need-to-rewrite-the-case-statement-for-every-field/33885426#comment55542881_33885426 was posted as an answer and an alternate to temp with a declared primary key   In that question a declared PK would be a more efficient join as then it knows to stop. In this question with a range with inequality is not the same.  This is not data just to illustrate a point - it is what I consider a complete answer.

Comment: I've updated the question to explain coherent: "The time ranges must not be contiguous (gaps between the time ranges are possible).". I will try out solutions tomorrow.

Comment: Must not be or may not be.  Just entry multiple time ranges.    "Must not be correlate with a normal day  ...  must be support also" is not clear.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I solved the problem with a left join very close to your solution.